# How to check last 3 rows for the same value?

Tags: mysql, group-by, limit

I want to check the last 3 rows - ordered by ID DESC - for the same value.

```
ID | Value
----------
52 | 20
51 | 20
50 | 20
49 | 34
48 | 72
47 | 12
46 | 19
45 | 55
44 | 8
```

For example, in my schema above, I'd like to get `3` or `TRUE` if the same `Value` is `20`.

I tried:

```
SELECT Value FROM mytable WHERE Value = '20' GROUP BY Value ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3;
```

But it's not working, I get all values, as if LIMIT is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) = 3, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') FROM (
SELECT
*
FROM
your_table
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 3
) sq
WHERE Value = 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove group by and run below query :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Value, ID FROM test1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3) AS A WHERE Value = '20';
```

Comment: Not working, I need to check for "20" in the last 3 rows. Your query will only allow me to select the last 3 rows containing "20".

Comment: please, check this query as per requirement.

Comment: This also works, I'll +1, as I've already accepted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tb.value from mytable tb where tb.id <=  ((select min(id) from mytable)+2)
```

This will only work if you are shure that values of your id's are every time  1 that previous/next id

or maybe this

```
select tb.value from mytable tb 
where rownum >=(select(max(rownum) from mytable)-2) 
order by tb.id desc
```